# Using BAM in EDI inbound and outbound process

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, edi, biztalk-bam

What functionality of BAM can we use in EDI?

I know BAM basics, but I don't know how can I use BAM in EDI inbound and outbound process.

So my question is how can we use BAM functionality in EDI inbound and outbound process?

Can any one let me know what can we track and how can I use BAM in EDI inbound and outbound process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either EDI or whatever scenarios you are targeting, There are several ways to implement BAM, you can either using the built in interceptor (TPE) or code your way using API calls. I usually don't like the TPE since it is rigid, I would go with using BAM API calls. Here is a good whitepaper you can read.

[Business Activity Monitoring in Depth for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd320628.aspx)